# Does "to tell apart" require "from" or "and"?

Tags: grammar, verbs, prepositions, government

Which of the following sentences are incorrect and why? Is it okay to use "and" in these phrases? And should "apart" be moved to the end of the sentence?

1. How to tell apart a raven from a crow?
2. How to tell apart a raven and a crow?
3. How to tell a raven from a crow apart?
4. How to tell a raven and a crow apart?

Also, is there any difference between "to tell A from B apart" and simply "to tell A from B", without "apart". And can "and" be used in this situation?

5. How to tell a raven from a crow?
6. How to tell a raven and a crow?

Comment: #1 and #3 are invalid. #2 and #4 are "okay" (but I'd say #5 is "better"). #6 isn't valid either - with just ***and*** linking the two bird types, you'd need a more specific verb, such as ***distinguish*** or ***differentiate*** to convey the sense of ***to tell apart*** (or just use something like ***identify*** and allow the context to imply that additional sense of *identify each **separately***).

Comment: How do you tell a raven and a crow _what_? This isn't a comparison